# Is it the case that $|x + y| ≤ |x| + |y| \iff |x - y| \le |x| + |y|$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I imagine that the difference of two vectors can be represented in the plane as follows: if vector x and y are drawn with their initial points coinciding, then the difference x - y is the vector from the terminal point of y to the terminal point of x.

This is the third side of a triangle with x and y as sides, and it is intuitive that the third side of the triangle is less than the sum of the other two sides, except that this time, the triangle inequality is written with x - y and not x + y. Is this equivalent to the more common way to write the triangle inequality? How do I show that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave intuition alone. Here, on a set such as $x\in X \implies -x\in X$

$$\begin{align}
\forall& x,y\in X\ \  |x-y| \le |x| + |y|
\\ \iff \forall& x,y\in X\ \  |x-(-y)| \le |x| + |-y|
\\ \iff \forall& x,y\in X\ \  |x+y| \le |x| + |y|
\end{align}
$$